# DJIA components multipliers

Tags: stocks, historical-data

I am doing a research for school and I am looking for a chart with the DJIA companies since 1950 to present and their stock price multiplier each year. Basically something like (values are fictive):

```
    Y | DJIA multiplier | Company1                  | Company 2                 | ...
      |                 | Part of DJIA | Multiplier | Part of DJIA | Multiplier | ...
    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    50| 4.5             | No           |    N/A     | Yes          | 3.4        | ...
    51| -3.2            | Yes          | -2         | Yes          | 0.5        | ...
    ...................
    ...................
```

Does anyone know where can I find something like this or how can I agrregate it from the Internet?

Answer (score 1):

You can create something like that by:

- registering at http://www.djindexes.com/averages/ and seeing if they publish historical constituent data
- visiting http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Historical_components_of_the_Dow_Jones_Industrial_Average to get a list of DJIA constituents for a given date.

You'll have to determine the PE ratio manually from the financial statements.  To get the PE ratio for each company, you can try [the Edgar database](http://www.sec.gov/edgar/searchedgar/companysearch.html), though I doubt it goes as far back as 1950.

[This blog](http://observationsandnotes.blogspot.com/2009/03/dow-price-to-earnings-ratios-since-1929.html) has a graph of the DJIA PE ratio from 1929 - 2009.